# cakephp3: how to implement facebook style or stack style user notifications using view cells?

Tags: javascript, cakephp, notifications, comet, cakephp-3.0

In Facebook, or StackOverflow, we notice that even when we DO NOT refresh the webpage, occasionally we get notified on the top navigation bar that certain events have happened.

Usually we term these as push notifications.

I have a working CakePHP 3 web app and the client requests for this kind of feature.

How do I implement this within CakePHP 3 framework?

There is this new thing called View Cells. Does that help?

I am opened to javascript solutions as well.

**EDIT**:

I can implement a json API if need be. I am proficient enough to do that. I am just not familiar with what to do in the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use JavaScript in one way or another, [**view cells**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html) are unrelated in the sense that they are purely server side technology that assists in view rendering.

The StackExchange sites [**are using WebSockets**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181196/what-does-stackexchange-use-web-sockets-for) for these notifications, Facebook used to use long polling AJAX requests if I remember correctly (not sure if they still do)...

There are various ways to implment something like that, the term you should be looking for is ***Comet***

- **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comet**
- **http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29**

Comment: in that case, what do you suggest for comet in a cake 3 app? websockets? I found http://socketo.me/ aka Rachet. Do you recommend it? What have you tried before for comet functions?

Comment: @KimStacks I haven't yet used any Comet stuff in a CakePHP based application, so I can't give you any tips (SO isn't the place for such opinions anyways), all I can say is that I had good experiences so far with WebSockets combined with Ratchet and also Socket.IO.

Comment: Got it. I understand that SO is not the best place for opinions, hence I did not fashion it into another question. What I do want is indeed your opinion and experience. Thank you!